# How can I solve mis-match error and correct the type?

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I am getting a

> mis-match error 13

when trying to run my code. I think I understand what is causing it but I can't figure out how to fix it.

The mis-match error is saying `RegionFcstAmt1 type is Variant/String` but the expression type to the right says Variant/Integer

```
Sub ShowUserForm1()

    TheAdjustment = ActiveCell.Value
    TheSubFamily = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
    Site = Cells(1, 1)

    UserForm1.RegionFcstAmt1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("REV DATA").Range("$AK:$BH"),Application.Match(ForecastDate, Sheets("REV DATA").Range("$AK$3:$BH$3"), 0)), Sheets("REV DATA").Range("$A:$A"), Sheets("TOTAL CHANGES").Range("$A6"), Sheets("REV DATA").Range("$H:$H"), TheSubFamily, Sheets("REV DATA").Range("$D:$D"), Sheets("TOTAL CHANGES").Range("$C6"), Sheets("REV DATA").Range("$E:$E"), Sheets("TOTAL CHANGES").Range("$D6:$F6"))), 0)

    UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: first and foremost, put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.  From there, you will need to dimension (e.g., `dim theadjustment as string`) every variable.  if you have dimensioned elsewhere, please add that to yoru post

Comment: Please tell in which line you get the error. Note that you use `ForecastDate` in your `Match` function but this variable is not declared or initialized with data (so it is empty).

Comment: I just didn't include the full code but the variables are declared. The error is coming from the UserForm1.RegionFcstAmt1.Value equation.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is, that you nested all your WorksheetFunctions without validating each of their results. I recommend to write each result of each WorksheetFunction into a variable and validate it before using it in another WorksheetFunction.

This way it is much easier to debug, because if there is an error in one of them you exactly get in which one.

First define your worksheet so you don't have to repeat that over and over

```
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Set wsData = ThisWorkbooks.Worksheets("REV DATA")

Dim wsTotal As Worksheet
Set wsTotal = ThisWorkbooks.Worksheets("TOTAL CHANGES")

Dim MatchResult As Double
MatchResult = Application.Match(ForecastDate, wsData.Range("AK3:BH3"), 0)
'note that here is the first problem because `ForecastDate` is not defined and therefore empty

'validate if match was successful if not exit
If IsError(MatchResult) Then
    MsgBox "'" & ForecastDate & "' did not match.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim IndexResult As Double
IndexResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(wsData.Range("AK:BH"), MatchResult)

Dim SumIfsResult As Double
SumIfsResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(IndexResult, wsData.Range("A:A"), wsTotal.Range("A6"), wsData.Range("H:H"), TheSubFamily, wsData.Range("D:D"), wsTotal.Range("C6"), wsData.Range("E:$"), wsTotal.Range("D6:F6"))), 0)
```

So now it becomes weird because you try to `SumProduct` the result of `SumIfs` (which returns only one value of type `Double`). So this doesn't make any sense at all, because for example the `SumProduct` of one value eg. `5` would be `5`.

The thing here is that you cannot *"translate"* a formula that you have in a cell one by one using WorksheetFunctions. Maybe have a look if the [Application.Evaluate method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) is something for you.

At least the above code shows the idea how you should work with WorksheetFunctions in combination with variables to validate the sub-results of each function.

*I think you  are a bit up the wrong tree with what you tried to do. I recommend to ask a new question, telling what you were actually trying to do. Actually the formula you tried will not work that way.*